# Applications of fractional boundary value problems

Tags: applications, fractional-calculus

I would like to ask if we study boundary conditions of fractional boundary value problem involving fractional boundary conditions, they have any real world applications or if boundary conditions do not involve fractional derivatives(Riemann Lioville or Caputo fractional derivatives), they don't have any known application?